# SQL Like operator doesn't work with the letter 'N'

Tags: sql, sql-server

I have a table like this

```
create table NHANVIEN
(
    HoNV nvarchar(15),
    TenLot nvarchar(15),
    TenNV nvarchar(15),
    MaNV char(9),
    NgSinh date,
    DChi nvarchar(30),
    Phai nvarchar(3),
    Luong float,
    Ma_NQL char(9),
    PHG int,

    primary key (MaNV)
);
```

[NHANVIEN table](https://i.stack.imgur.com/geC7L.jpg)

I have problem with this query

```
select HoNV, TenLot, TenNV
from NHANVIEN
where TenNV like N'N%'
```

After executing the above query, it should have return the 3rd and the 4th row; but somehow mine didn't return any rows.
I've tried with the names that don't have letter 'g' after the 'N' and it worked.
Thanks for your help

Edited: the original query is `where HoNV like N'N%'`. I just tested with other column to check if it worked

Comment: oh yes, my mistake

Comment: What is your dbms? What is your collation? Is "Ng" perhaps a single character (digraph) in your collation?

Comment: my collation is Vietnamese_CI_AS, and what do you mean by dbms?

Comment: Dbms: Do you use Sql Server, or MySQL, or Oracle or something else?

Comment: [Looks like](https://collation-charts.org/mssql/mssql.042A.1258.Vietnamese_CI_AS.html) "Ng" is indeed a single character in that collation. So "Nguyen" doesn't start with "N", it starts with "Ng"

Comment: I'm using SQL Server 2012

Comment: Sample data as formatted text is so much easier for us. I can't copy-and-paste from pictures.

Answer (score 1):

It seems that my problem is due to my Vietnamese_CI_AS collation. Using the default collation should be worked